# Comparator as lambda

Tags: lambda, kotlin, comparator

I've the following method in [Java library](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView#sortable-data):

```java
public void setColumnComparator(final int columnIndex, final Comparator<T> columnComparator)
```

Idea says it has the following prorotype:

```
setColumnComparator(columnIndex: Int, columnComparator: ((Any!, Any!) -> Int)!)
```

How can I use it? I know it will be `String`, so I want something like this, but it doesn't compile.

```
setColumnComparator(0, Comparator<String> { a, b -> a.compareTo(b) }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the `Comparator` interface?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I assume that you the `Comparator` interface is `java.util.Comparator`?

Comment: Yes, it expects `java.util.Comparator`.

Comment: And what's the type of the instance that you're trying to call this on?

Comment: https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView#sortable-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look more carefully, you need to pass comparator which compares *complete* values, not values in the column. So let's say the type of data in your table is `Car` (so that you have a `SortableTableView<Car>`) and the first column contains model names. Then you'd write

```
setColumnComparator(0, { a, b -> a.modelName.compareTo(b.modelName) }
```

Or better:

```
setColumnComparator(0, compareBy({ it.modelName })
```

(see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html)

From the signature IDEA shows, you might have a `SortableTableView<Any>` or a `SortableTableView<*>` instead. This really should be changed to a more specific type. But even without it, if you could have a `Car` or a `Book`:

```
compareBy({ (it as? Car)?.modelName }, { (it as? Book)?.title })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that your `SortableTableView`'s generic type parameter is `String`, you could cast it to a `SortableTableView<String>` and then make the call to it:

```
(tableView as SortableTableView<String>).setColumnComparator(1, { x, y ->
    x.compareTo(y)
})
```

Alternatively, you could cast the parameters that the `Comparator` takes individually:

```
tableView.setColumnComparator(1, { x, y -> 
    (x as String).compareTo(y as String) 
})
```

Comment: Some columns will be `Date`, so I can't use the first solution. The second solution gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: cz.foobar.ClientsFragment$onViewCreated$1 cannot be cast to java.util.Comparator`

Comment: You're right, I can reproduce this issue as well. It's certainly interesting, I'll see if I can look into it later - it's a weird thing to get a runtime error about.